# Manipulate Chart Select Multiple Time-Series

Tags: r, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I have created the plot below, so that I can easily compare multiple timeseries over different sections of time.  I would next like to add a selector so that I can pick multiple timeseries to view on the plot at the same time, and uncheck the ones I don't want to see on the plot.

code:

```
y<-series1
r<-series2
s<-series3

require(graphics)
manipulate( 
ts.plot(ts(y[x:(x+100)]),ts(r[x:(x+100)]),ts(s[x:(x+100)]),ts(t[x:    (x+100)]),ts(h[x:(x+100)]), gpars=list(col = c("red","green","gray")))
 ,  
 x=slider(1,length(y)))
```

data:

```
dput(series1[1:10])
c(9.5, 9, 14.5, 22.5, 13, 16, 22, 31.5, 51, 43)


dput(series2[1:10])
c(20.3368220204774, 18.0733372276398, 16.61695493123, 15.6798824136643, 
15.0769466973063, 14.6890028922692, 14.4393902191708, 14.2787832298018, 
14.175444706505, 14.1089541357078)

dput(series3[1:10])
c(17.8189147557743, 22.3815592342001, 16.108169527143, 21.0654757276344, 
16.3878646132368, 18.9345933680916, 16.634277276197, 15.4322081636797, 
20.2884280389731, 12.2089595405668)
```

Comment: I can't seem to download the package, graphics.

Comment: And also what does each dput being assigned to? I'm terribly confused. Please rewrite stuff!

Also, please tell us to download the "minipulate" package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
y<-c(9.5, 9, 14.5, 22.5, 13, 16, 22, 31.5, 51, 43)
r<-c(20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14)
require(graphics)
require(manipulate)
manipulate({ 
  lines <- list(if (chk.y) ts(y), if(chk.r) ts(r))
  cols <- c(if (chk.y) "red", if (chk.r) "green")
  do.call(ts.plot, c(lines, list(gpars=list(col=cols, xlab="t", ylab="y"))))
}, 
  chk.y=checkbox(TRUE, "y"),
  chk.r=checkbox(TRUE, "r")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a slight modification to your code did the trick.  `y<-tsValidation
r<-Acast$mean

require(graphics)
require(manipulate)
manipulate({ 
  lines <- list(if (chk.y) ts(y[x:(x+100)]), if(chk.r) ts(r[x:(x+100)]))
  cols <- c(if (chk.y) "red", if (chk.r) "green")
  do.call(ts.plot, c(lines, list(gpars=list(col=cols, xlab="t", ylab="y"))))
}, 
chk.y=checkbox(TRUE, "y"),
chk.r=checkbox(TRUE, "r"),
x=slider(1,length(y))
)`